# Exposing API for use by Command Line Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple application that tracks distractions (http://distracker.herokuapp.com/)

I'm trying to expose an API and build a gem that people can use to access their study sessions and make new distractions via the command line.

Here's the source code: https://github.com/justuseapen/distracker

I've gotten as far as putting JSON responders in the controllers, but I'm not sure how to handle command line authentication (the way Heroku does) so that users only need to login once.

On top of that, I think I should be using Thor to build the gem, but I couldn't say for certain.

I have no idea how to write specs for this, and I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The heroku gem and other gems like it use .netrc in the home directory for the user to store login information. When using a .netrc you may want to look at implementing oAuth on the server in order store an auth token instead of username and password. This is to prevent the storing of secure credentials in unencrypted plaintext.